# Yocto, Meta-selinux does not work on raspberry pi 3

Tags: raspberry-pi3, yocto, selinux

I realize a yocto image for a raspberry pi 3. I want to install selinux on the image with the Meta-selinux. The compilation works, but selinux remains disabled even if it is in enforcing or permissive mode in the / etc / selinux / config file. I also tried adding "selinux = 1 security = selinux" in the cmdline.txt file of the bootloader, but selinux is still disabled.

Here is what I added in my local.conf:

```
RPI_USE_U_BOOT = "1"
ENABLE_UART = "1"
INHERIT += "rm_work"
DISTRO_FEATURES_append = " acl xattr pam selinux"
PREFERRED_PROVIDER_virtual/refpolicy = "refpolicy-mls"
IMAGE_INSTALL_append = " packagegroup-core-selinux"
```

Here is what I added in my bblayers.conf:

```
BBLAYERS ?= " \
  /home/.../poky/meta \
  /home/.../meta-poky \
  /home/.../meta-yocto-bsp \
  /home/.../meta-openembedded/meta-oe \
  /home/.../meta-openembedded/meta-networking \
  /home/.../meta-openembedded/meta-multimedia \
  /home/.../meta-openembedded/meta-python \
  /home/.../meta-selinux \
  /home/.../meta-raspberrypi \
  "
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Any update, i am facing same issue